# Find a string and append it to next line using awk

Tags: unix, sed, awk

Input file:

```
DAN|a@gmail.com,c@yahoo.co.in,abc@gmail.com  
NAB|a@gmail.com  
PAT|a@gmail.com  
DAN|y@gmail.com  
NAB|y@yahoo.in  
PAT|z@redhat.com,abc@gmail.com  
DAN|y@gmail.com,abc@gmail.com  
NAB|b@yahoo.co.in  
PAT|c@uix.xo.in  
DAN|y@gmail.com  
NAB|b@yahoo.co.in  
PAT|c@uix.xo.in
```

consider 1st line, there are multiple records which are ',' seperated. Find ',' seperated record. If ',' seperated record found in 1st line then a place it into next line and append it with 'DAN|', whatever the string at the beginning , that should be appended. So output should be :

```
DAN|a@gmail.com  
DAN|c@yahoo.co.in     
DAN|abc@gmail.com  
NAB|a@gmail.com  
PAT|a@gmail.com  
DAN|y@gmail.com  
NAB|y@yahoo.in  
PAT|z@redhat.com  
PAT|abc@gmail.com  
DAN|y@gmail.com  
DAN|abc@gmail.com  
NAB|b@yahoo.co.in  
PAT|c@uix.xo.in  
DAN|y@gmail.com  
NAB|b@yahoo.co.in  
PAT|c@uix.xo.in
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`, using two delimiters:

```
awk -F "[|,]" '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1 "|" $i }' file
```

Here's another way using a single delimiter:

```
awk -F, '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print (i>1 ? substr($0,0,4) : "") $i }' file
```

Results:

```
DAN|a@gmail.com
DAN|c@yahoo.co.in
DAN|abc@gmail.com  
NAB|a@gmail.com  
PAT|a@gmail.com  
DAN|y@gmail.com  
NAB|y@yahoo.in  
PAT|z@redhat.com
PAT|abc@gmail.com  
DAN|y@gmail.com
DAN|abc@gmail.com  
NAB|b@yahoo.co.in  
PAT|c@uix.xo.in  
DAN|y@gmail.com  
NAB|b@yahoo.co.in  
PAT|c@uix.xo.in
```

Comment: +1 for the first.. The second only works with names of length 3 why not something like `substr($0,0,match($0,/\|/))`.

Comment: @sudo_O: Thanks mate. The names with length 3 look reasonably consistent given the input. But a very good suggestion if that can vary. Also, it's important to remember that only `gawk` users can use the `match()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
awk -F'[|,]' '{gsub(/,/,RS $1 "|")}1' file
```